# SQLPLUS formatting output in excel

Tags: linux, oracle, shell, sqlplus

Below is the code to retrieve data from DB and output it in excel

```
sqlplus -s ${uidpwd} <<EOF
SET PAGESIZE 50000
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET MARKUP HTML ON
SET NUM 24
SPOOL Extract.xls

whenever oserror exit 9
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode  
@${SQL_SCRIPT}
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET ECHO OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SPOOL OFF
SET MARKUP HTML OFF
quit;
EOF
```

But what i see in excel report is all numbers in excel are with exponential like "5.30056E+15"
i tried below options, but none of them worked

```
SET NUMBERFORMAT '9999999999999999999999'

SET NUMWIDTH 20
```

in SQL i tried below

```
to_char(conf_num, '999999999999999999999999')

SELECT ' '||conf_num "Confirmation Number"
```

Also i have ``` exec > ${LOGPATH}/log.``date +"%y%m%d"``.log 2>&1 ``` in my script, Query out put is getting written in to this log file, how to avoid that? It should have only error logs.

Comment: Which version of SQL Plus are you using? If 12.2, you can simply use the CSV markup.

Comment: @BobC, Yes i can but the requirement is Excel sheet (xls)

Comment: Did it occur to you to look at the Excel formatting? This has nothing to do with Oracle or SQL\*Plus formatting.

Comment: Have your Target Excel file pre-formatted and then simply copy paste the data from your csv file opened in another excel.

Comment: @KaushikNayak, the excel report is generated as part of automated shell script scheduled to run daily. We cannot do this manually as you suggested.